# Porkchop plots/launch windows for Sun-Earth L2 to Mars transfers?

Tags: trajectory, lagrangian-points, hohmann-transfer, trajectory-design, launch-window

I've been using Earth-Mars launch windows, found with NASA's [Trajectory Browser](https://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/) and [EasyPorkchop](http://sdg.aero.upm.es/index.php/online-apps/porkchop-plot), as launch windows from the Sun-Earth L2 Lagrange point to Mars, with the logic that since the L2 point is much closer to Mars than the Earth is, they should be equivalent. However, I've had this nagging doubt that since L2 is about 1.5 million km away from the Earth, maybe there are epochs that are even better suited for an L2-Mars transfer. Are there any resources or Lambert solvers that can generate porkchop plots or launch windows for a transfer from L2 to Mars for specified epochs? Custom objects can usually be specified in these tools with their ephemeris data, so maybe that applies to L2 (JPL Horizons has ephemeris data for the Sun-Earth-Moon L2, which I assume is the same as Sun-Earth L2). Considering the L2 point isn't a planet with gravity, is that even possible?

Comment: I think [HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/) has pseudo state vectors for Lagrange points. That should be plenty for the existing tools

Comment: I get the error "GMLOADR: Unknown target code: 32" when I try to generate osculating orbital elements ephemeris for SEMB-L2 (which EasyPorkchop takes as its input to specify an object). I can still generate vector tables however, so maybe I can convert L2's orbital state vectors to the orbital elements I want.